# Python - Easiest way to define multiple global variables

Tags: python, variables, global

I am trying to look for an easy way to define multiple global variables from inside a function or class.

The obvious option is to do the following:

```
global a,b,c,d,e,f,g......
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
.....
```

This is a simplified example but essentially I need to define dozens of global variables based on the input of a particular function.  Ideally I would like to take care of defining the global name and value without having to update both the value and defining the global name independently.

To add some more clarity.

I am looking for the python equivalent of this (javascript):

```
var a = 1
  , b = 2
  , c = 3
  , d = 4
  , e = 5;
```

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. This is the entirely wrong way to do almost anything. You need to review lists, dictionaries, functions, and return values.

Comment: There is __very__ certainly a way to write your code without a single global.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I completely agree, the problem here is am editing a very poorly written project.  To rewrite it though would be an extensive amount of effort, so I am stuck between a rock and a hard place and essentially just trying to come up with the be solution given my constraints.  Which are defining values for global variables from within a function.

Comment: Is this valid python syntax? `global a,b,c,d,e,f,g......`. I'm looking for a terse way to declare a bunch of global variables as being global inside a function instead of the line by line declaration for each variable.

Comment: @jxramos yes, it is valid syntax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Alright, I'm new myself and this has been a big issue for me as well and I think it has to do with the phrasing of the question (I phrased it the same way when googling and couldn't quite find an answer that was relevant to what I was trying to do). Please, someone correct me if there's a reason I should not do this, but...

The best way to set up a list of global variables would be to set up a class for them in that module.

```
class globalBS():
    bsA = "F"
    bsB = "U"
```

now you can call them, change them, etc. in any other function by referencing them as such:

```
print(globalBS.bsA)
```

would print "F" in any function on that module. The reason for this is that python treats classes as modules, so this works out well for setting up a list of global variables- such as when trying to make an interface with multiple options such as I'm currently doing, without copying and pasting a huge list of globals in every function. I would just keep the class name as short as possible- maybe one or two characters instead of an entire word.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant idea to use a Class variable to deal situation where global variable use is unavoidable.

Answer (score 50):

You could just unpack the variables:

```
global x, y, z
x, y, z = 4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 5):

The `globals()` builtin function refers to the global variables in the current module. You can use it just like a normal dictionary

```
globals()['myvariable'] = 5
print(myvariable) # returns 5
```

Repeat this for all you variables.

However, you most certainly shouldn't do that

Comment: `globals()` is probably an even worse idea than using `global`.

Comment: how could he use `global` during runtime to define variables with unknown names and values coming from user input??

Answer (score 3):

If they are conceptually related one option is to have them in a dictionary:

```
global global_dictionary
global_dictionary = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

But as it was commented in your question, this is not the best approach to handle the problem that generated this question.

Comment: Firstly, globals are the wrong way to go. Secondly, dictionaries are mutable and can be mutated without being reassigned.

Comment: @Martinbaste, I considered this method, but then it requires editing all of the code that calls upon the global variables already....

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 1
globe = {}
while count < 27:
    yy = chr(96 + count)
    xx = count
    globe[yy] = xx
    count += 1
print((globe))
```

Comment: This will create a dictionary assigning the numbers to the letters. You can access by x = globe['a']..

Comment: 1st, you should put the explanation as part of the answer, not in the comments. 2nd, using a dictionary was already given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40993013/2745495.

Comment: I can't understand your editor. I try to explain but get error messages saying it expects code. As questioner requested, my example was the easiest way to assign numbers to all the letters.